# EMR with multiple encryption key providers

Tags: apache-spark, encryption, spark-streaming, emr, amazon-emr

I'm running EMR cluster with enabled [s3 client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-emrfs-encryption-cse.html) using custom key provider. But now I need to write data to multiple s3 destinations using different encryption schemas:

1. CSE custom key provider
2. CSE-KMS

Is it possible to configure EMR to use both encryption types by defining some kind of mapping between s3 bucket and encryption type?

Alternatively since I use spark structured streaming to process and write data to s3 I'm wondering if it's possible to disable encryption on EMRFS but then enable CSE for each stream separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to support any file systems scheme and configure it individually. For example:

```
# custom encryption key provider
fs.s3x.cse.enabled = true
fs.s3x.cse.materialsDescription.enabled = true
fs.s3x.cse.encryptionMaterialsProvider = my.company.fs.encryption.CustomKeyProvider

#no encryption
fs.s3u.cse.enabled = false

#AWS KMS
fs.s3k.cse.enabled = true
fs.s3k.cse.encryptionMaterialsProvider = com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider
fs.s3k.cse.kms.keyId = some-kms-id
```

And then to use it in spark like this:

```
StreamingQuery writeStream = session
        .readStream()
        .schema(RecordSchema.fromClass(TestRecord.class))
        .option(OPTION_KEY_DELIMITER, OPTION_VALUE_DELIMITER_TAB)
        .option(OPTION_KEY_QUOTE, OPTION_VALUE_QUOTATION_OFF)
        .csv(“s3x://aws-s3-bucket/input”)
        .as(Encoders.bean(TestRecord.class))
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .format("parquet")
        .option("path", “s3k://aws-s3-bucket/output”)
        .option("checkpointLocation", “s3u://aws-s3-bucket/checkpointing”)
        .start();
```

Ta handle this I’ve implemented a custom Hadoop file system (extends `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`) that delegates calls to real file system but with modified configurations.

```
// Create delegate FS
this.config.set("fs.s3n.impl", “com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem”);
this.config.set("fs.s3n.impl.disable.cache", Boolean.toString(true));
this.delegatingFs = FileSystem.get(s3nURI(originalUri, SCHEME_S3N), substituteS3Config(conf));
```

Configuration that passes to delegating file system should take all original settings and replace any occurrences of `fs.s3*.` with `fs.s3n.`.

```
private Configuration substituteS3Config(final Configuration conf) {
    if (conf == null) return null;

    final String fsSchemaPrefix = "fs." + getScheme() + ".";
    final String fsS3SchemaPrefix = "fs.s3.";
    final String fsSchemaImpl = "fs." + getScheme() + ".impl";
    Configuration substitutedConfig = new Configuration(conf);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> configEntry : conf) {
        String propName = configEntry.getKey();
        if (!fsSchemaImpl.equals(propName)
            && propName.startsWith(fsSchemaPrefix)) {
            final String newPropName = propName.replace(fsSchemaPrefix, fsS3SchemaPrefix);
            LOG.info("Substituting property '{}' with '{}'", propName, newPropName);
            substitutedConfig.set(newPropName, configEntry.getValue());
        }
    }

    return substitutedConfig;
}
```

Besides that make sure that delegating fs receives uris and paths with supporting scheme and returns paths with custom scheme

```
@Override
public FileStatus getFileStatus(final Path f) throws IOException {
    FileStatus status = this.delegatingFs.getFileStatus(s3Path(f));
    if (status != null) {
        status.setPath(customS3Path(status.getPath()));
    }
    return status;
}

private Path s3Path(final Path p) {
    if (p.toUri() != null && getScheme().equals(p.toUri().getScheme())) {
        return new Path(s3nURI(p.toUri(), SCHEME_S3N));
    }
    return p;
}

private Path customS3Path(final Path p) {
    if (p.toUri() != null && !getScheme().equals(p.toUri().getScheme())) {
        return new Path(s3nURI(p.toUri(), getScheme()));
    }
    return p;
}

private URI s3nURI(final URI originalUri, final String newScheme) {
     try {
         return new URI(
             newScheme,
             originalUri.getUserInfo(),
             originalUri.getHost(),
             originalUri.getPort(),
             originalUri.getPath(),
             originalUri.getQuery(),
             originalUri.getFragment());
     } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
         LOG.warn("Unable to convert URI {} to {} scheme", originalUri, newScheme);
     }

     return originalUri;
}
```

The final step is to register custom file system with Hadoop (`spark-defaults` classification)

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3x.impl = my.company.fs.DynamicS3FileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3u.impl = my.company.fs.DynamicS3FileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3k.impl = my.company.fs.DynamicS3FileSystem
```

Comment: Subclassing the AWS connector & overriding its `initialize` method to patch the config there would be the tactic I'd take; lifting the per-bucket config from org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils. That should let you retrofit per-bucket config to emr's connector.

Answer (score 2):

When you use EMRFS, you can specify per-bucket configs in the format:

`fs.s3.bucket.<bucket name>.<some.configuration>`

So, for example, to turn off CSE except for a bucket `s3://foobar`, you can set:

```
   "Classification": "emrfs-site",
   "Properties": {
      "fs.s3.cse.enabled": "false",
      "fs.s3.bucket.foobar.cse.enabled": "true",
      [your other configs as usual]
   }
```

Please note that it must be `fs.s3` and not `fs.{arbitrary-scheme}` like `fs.s3n`.

Comment: This works for me. I read data from one bucket which is encrypted, and save the decrypted data to another bucket without encryption. Is there link to official documentation that I can read further on this EMRFS feature?

Comment: I asked the EMR team to document this before I posted it publicly. They promised they would. Unfortunately I know about it through reading the source code and internal issue trackers. It was a workaround for a big customer, as these things usually go at AWS. Maybe they’ll announce it at reInvent with some fanfare! 

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Amazon EMR, but on hadoop's s3a connector, you can set the encryption policy on a bucket-by-bucket basis. However, S3A doesn't support client side encryption on account of it breaking fundamental assumptions about file lengths (the amount of data you can read MUST == the length in a directory listing/getFileStatus call).

I expect amazon to do something similar. You may be able to create a custom Hadoop `Configuration` object with the different settings & use that to retrieve the filesystem instance used to save things. Tricky in Spark though.

Comment: Unfortunately [EMR doesn't support s3a scheme](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-file-system-s3/) yet so it's not an option. Will post shortly a solution I'm working on right now where I have a custom file system that actually creates a new `Configuration` object with required settings.

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk Did you ever get this to work? Can you post it?

Comment: @ChoppyTheLumberjack I posted solution already. See accepted answer

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk Is that the full implementation of your custom s3 (starting with \@Override public FileStatus getFileStatus ...) or are there many other things I also have to extend with this delegator pattern?

Comment: @ChoppyTheLumberjack It's just one example how substitution happens. Since the delegator extends `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` it requires to implement all abstract methods each of which replaces 's3x' with 's3' and back 's3' to 's3x' when return result