# EMR + Spark + KMS - save decrypted data

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-kms

We are processing KMS client side encrypted data in EMR using spark. I am able to successfully process the encrypted data using the following configuration but even the aggregated data written to s3 is encrypted. Is there a way to write unencrypted data to s3 with these settings on ? If not, how can we decrypt it before loading it in RDS for reporting ?

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.cse.materialsDescription.enabled", "true");
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.cse.encryptionMaterialsProvider", "com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider");
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.cse.kms.keyId","arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:abcd");
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.cse.enabled", "true");
```

print('Writing to directory...' + OUTPUT_DIR)
formatted_ags.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(OUTPUT_DIR)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635718/emr-with-multiple-encryption-key-providers) where described a workaround how to use different encryption configs per custom uri scheme.

Answer (score 0):

To configure using different encryption key / decrypt while saving data, we can follow below strategy.

Configure a new file system and you can name it like s3X where X can be replaced by any characters.
One example configuration is as below.

```
   {
      "classification":"emrfs-site",
      "properties":{
         "fs.s3k.cse.kms.keyId":"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX",
         "fs.s3k.cse.enabled":"true",         
         "fs.s3k.cse.encryptionMaterialsProvider":"com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider",         
      }
   },
   {
      "classification":"spark-defaults",
      "properties":{
         "spark.hadoop.fs.s3k.impl":"com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem",
  }
```

And use s3k protocol while saving the output.

If we you want disable encryption we can configure like `“fs.s3k.cse.enabled”:“false”`